# Uploading in background thread in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, upload

I know it's possible to do a few things on the background thread - VOIP, location and audio.
How about uploading? Can I upload in a background thread? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course. That's a great use of a background thread. If it's Http you're using this library is very useful. It's http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response
:)

I've heard of that library, but the problem is - what if I want to upload several videos and images, as it may take a long while (not a few seconds that can be handled when the app is going to the background).

When the app goes to the background, will the upload continue?
Again, this is because I heard there are only 3 things allowed to be done in a background thread, and we are not doing VOIP, location or audio.

Also, will the error handling be easy as well?

Comment: yes, it will continue in the background. The flag to set is setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground. It has error handling. Not sure if I'd say it's easy, but it's not too bad. Don't forget ASIHTTP is of course HTTP. For FTP etc. you'll most likely need something else.