# iOS app: Uploading multiple files in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, upload, background

For iOS, I am aware that apps can upload in the background, as according to this thread:
[Uploading in background thread in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430828/uploading-in-background-thread-in-ios)

When I refer to "background", I mean the user has clicked the home button, using another app, or the phone's screen is off.

Follow-up Questions:

1.
Is there a timeout limit to the background uploading? This may be an issue if the file being uploaded is huge.

2.
Is it possible to upload a list of files in the background, or does it only support the finishing of one upload that was in progress before the user switched to another app?

3.
I suppose if the user quits the app completely, the upload will be stopped? Quitting completely as in, user double clicks home button, touches and holds down on the app until it starts shaking, then clicks the "X" to shut it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

1)  The timeout limit is probably server - imposed, but you can certainly add some timeout detection code on the client (iOS) side.

2)  Uploading a "list of files" is effectively the same as uploading a file.  A list of files is just another file, effectively.

3)  If the app is killed, yes, everything (and all the background threads) get killed along with it.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply. Just to confirm, uploading in the background means that the app is no longer active, but hasn't been killed. Inactive as in: user has clicked the home button, is playing with another app, or the phone screen is off.

Is that correct?

Comment: Ohhh, well now that you've edited your question to talk about background *apps* and not threads, that makes things somewhat different.  My points 1, 2 & 3 are still valid, but I do not know how much can be done while an app itself is in the background.  Everything I've read says that processing for backgrounded apps is minimal.